# How to properly toggle themes on dynamic page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use the following jQuery code to toggle between two themes (day/night) for my website.

```
$('#switch').on('click', function () { $('*').toggleClass('switch-bg'); });
```

Everything works as expected when I click the button identified as "switch" which adds/removes the class "switch-bg" for the available CSS properties (in this case, the body property).

Example:

```
body {background: #fff;}   /* DAY mode (default) */
body.switch-bg {background: #000;}   /* NIGHT mode */
```

My problem begins when I am in "night mode" and some content is loaded into the page in the default state "day mode" which results in a mix between the two.

More details:

- All dynamic content (external HTML) is loaded into a div (internal) in my homepage via hyperlinks within the navigation menu. This is achieved using jQuery.
- The toggle works on the dynamic content only if the content is already loaded. If you re-load the same or a different content, the problem will occur where the loaded content is in the default state "day mode" and the homepage is still in "night mode".

I want everything to stay in "night mode" while that option is selected.

Comment: Can you improve the title of this article? Other people would find it more easily.

Comment: @zaclummys any suggestions?

Comment: Something like _How to properly toggle themes on dynamic page?_ would sound good.

Comment: Is there anything against making the class and corresponding css global to `body` or a container div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution to your problem can be:

- Instead of changing the classes of all elements, just toggle a class in `html`. In this case, **nightly**.

  `$('#switch').on('click', function () { $('html').toggleClass('nightly'); });`
- Instead of theming an element based on its own class, theme it based on the class of a parent element. In this case, `html`.

  ```
  .button {
      background-color: #fff; // day mode
  }

  .nightly .button {
      background-color: #000; // night mode
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the user's preference. Read the location storage entry every time you load new content and set the class depending on the saved option.

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply the class to *everything* (*). Just apply it to the body, and style based on context.

e.g.

```
.some-element {background: #fff;}   /* DAY mode (default) */
.switch-bg .some-element {background: #000;}   /* NIGHT mode */
```

Comment: I was using (*) just for testing. Also, it didn't work applied to the body but it did to the html. Thanks Sam!

Comment: What do you mean that applying to the body didn't work? Can you add your css to the question?

Comment: @clabe45 My guess is he's just applying the styling _to_ the body, meaning it that case the rule needs to be `.switch-bg.body-el` to work (and why adding it to `html` worked.

Comment: This is what I meant by adding to html `$('#switch').on('click', function () { $('html').toggleClass('switch-bg'); });` while using the CSS syntax mentioned above for 20+ elements across the website.